# Playframewrok [Scala]: Put different parameters other than @title and @content in main.scala.html

Tags: scala, playframework

I have my sidebar menus located in the `main.scala.html` as a default and put all the other contents in separate `*.scala.html` pages.

I realized that I need to put `user id` on sidebar menu and it has to appear all the time. Is it possible to put other parameters in `main.scala.html` page while calling different pages? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first lets discuss this: why we want to pass parameters between views?

The reason is that you can factor out components; and reuse them throughout your views. For example, you can 
imagine that you have a web app that has the topbar, body, and footer. You simply can factor out topbar, and footer and reuse 
them throughout your views files.

Second, you can pass, almost any arbitray or functional types (String, Int, List[String], etc) to the views, either from the controller to views; or views to views.

Lets take a look at this (`userPage.scala.html`):

```
@(name: String, lastname: String, location: String)
```

Then you can call the userPage as following:

```
@userPage("Jessica", "Jones", "Hell Kitchen")
```

You are calling the `userPage` and passing the arguments.

Sometimes you want to send a form (e.g., signin/feedback/signup form) to the views; that is not a problem either. You can do the following (signin.scala.html):

```
@(singin: Form[Signin])
```

Where you create the form and its related case class (Signin in our example); and pass it from the controller to the views.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just put it, like

```
@(title: String, id: String)(content: Html)
...
```

Then you can call it like

```
@main(title = "Home", id=myId) {
...
```

Here you can read more about how to put parameters in a template:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#template-parameters

You can use a dependency injection in the case of parameters that often used: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplatesDependencyInjection

Comment: when it comes to the universal page for main.html, having second param (in this case, id) requires this param to be existed in other scala.html pages. any ideas for this issue?

Comment: It does not, you can use default. Look here how the template is called with `scripts` parameter and without : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases#moreScripts-and-moreStyles-equivalents